# How much is known about those liquid metal droplets orbiting the Earth? (e.g. sizes, composition, orbits...) Are any actually tracked?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, physics, debris, nuclear, chemistry

The question [Orbit Guardians - bs, right?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51506/12102) mentions a company proposing a smallsat that will capture then give a roughly 200 m/s retrograde "kick" to liquid metal [NaK alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium%E2%80%93potassium_alloy) droplets in LEO circa 800 to 900 km, apparently leaked by some old nuclear reactors still in orbit.

- [How many nuclear fission reactors have been launched into space? How many are still there?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27908/12102)
- [Most recent launch of a nuclear reactor, and current barriers to launching the next one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34139/12102)

Apparently these droplets are believed to be liquid not solid, but I think that would depend on several things, including their chemical composition (a wide range of ratios are soluble) and their emissivity = 1 - albedo.

Pristine metal is presumably shiny with very high albedo $A$, but they could have space dust, dirt or other non-soluble contaminants their surfaces making them darker.

For a sphere (blob of metal, planet, or otherwise) the equilibrium temperature is [given as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature#Derivation):

$$T_{Eq} = \left(\frac{I_0 (1-A)}{4 \sigma} \right)^{1/4}$$

where $I_0$ is the solar intensity at 1 AU of about 1361 W/m<sup>2</sup> and $\sigma$ is the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) 5.67E-08 W/m<sup>2</sup>/K<sup>4</sup>.

For example:

```
albedo      T_Eq (K)      T_Eq (C)
 0.1          271           -2
 0.5          234          -39
 0.9          157         -116
```

**Question(s):**

1. How much is known *or at least generally believed to be true* about those liquid metal droplets orbiting the Earth? (e.g. sizes, composition (stoichiometry), contamination, albedo, temperature...)
2. Are any actually tracked? Are any specific orbits known? Or would a spacecraft have to go out there and scour the orbits of old nuclear reactors looking for them?
3. Have any individual droplets ever been detected by any means, or are they strictly *deduced* to exist?

While individually small, the [480,000,000 West Ford <s>dipoles</s> needles](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36096/12102) made a "shiny" radar target. These droplets are old and spread out and not so numerous, so it's conceivable that they've never actually been observed.

---

[image: phase diagram of NaK alloy]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_potassium_sodium_s_l.svg)

> Legend: Na - melting point of pure sodium, K - melting point of pure potassium, E - eutectic point, P - peritectic point, blue line - melting point of eutectic mixture, black line - melting point of compound Na2K, red line - melting point of surplus (Z. Anorg. Chem. 74 (1912) 152-156)

Comment: Liquid? They should freeze at about -8C, for the ration NaK used... Being moderately reflective metallic spheres, they should stabilize at a temperature of -80C or so.. Simple empirical prof they are not liquid: NaK has a very low but **non-zero** vapor pressure in the liquid state. If these droplets were still liquid, they should have evaporated ages ago. And if they ARE liquid, why bother to try to shove them to deorbit. Just *whack* with a giant flyswatter, breaking them up into zillions of microscopic fragments, that are mostly harmless in themselves and will de-orbit very quickly.

Comment: @PcMan write all that wisdom up as an answer post and let people vote on it

Comment: @TooTea thanks for that! I swear it was my fingers or at most my [reptile brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triune_brain) that did that. If it were my conscious mipselling I would have added an h in there somewhere or ended with two n's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not able to address your entire question, but I think I can answer questions 2 & 3.

> 2. Are any actually tracked? Are any specific orbits known? Or would a spacecraft have to go out there and scour the orbits of old nuclear reactors looking for them?
> 3. Have any individual droplets ever been detected by any means, or are they strictly deduced to exist?

It turns about that many of these are tracked.  If you look at the catalog available from [space-track.org](https://space-track.org) (a convenient interface is available at n2yo.com) you will find more that 100 coolant debris objets along with their TLEs, so they have been definitively detected and tracked.

If you want to see the list from [n2yo.org](https://n2yo.org) try this search: https://www.n2yo.com/database/?q=coolant#results.

As an example, here is the info for one:

```
NORAD ID: 39645  
Int'l Code: 1987-060N  
Perigee: 777.9 km  
Apogee: 808.1 km  
Inclination: 65.0 °  
Period: 100.6 minutes  
Semi major axis: 7163 km  
RCS: Unknown  
Launch date: July 10, 1987 
Source: Commonwealth of Independent States (former USSR) (CIS) 
Launch site: TYURATAM MISSILE AND SPACE COMPLEX (TTMTR) 

Note: This is SATELLITE DEBRIS

Two Line Element Set (TLE): 
1 39645U 87060N   21283.09775667  .00000019  00000-0  44430-4 0  9990
2 39645  65.0104 133.5701 0021064 269.3178  90.5493 14.31758015393611
```